# Luggage & transfer flight question, Hong Kong Airlines

Tags: luggage, short-connections, connecting-flights, hkg

Question: I’m wanting to catch a Hong Kong Airlines flight from Los Angeles to Bali, LAX > Hong Kong (HKG) > Bali (DPS). There is a transfer flight stop in Hong Kong with only 1 hour in between and both flights are on Hong Kong Airlines.

With being such a short time in between I’m curious, does the luggage automatically get transferred to the next flight OR do I have to grab the checked bag and go thru all the airport check in stops? Cause if so... 1 hour doesn’t sound like enough time to grab luggage, check in, and get on transfer flight. Also, the flight would be purchased straight from HK Airlines as a round trip.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your luggage will be checked through; you can verify this when you check it in.

One hour is quite tight and, if your incoming flight is delayed, there's a good chance that you'll miss the connection. However, the airline is obliged to put you on the next available flight so this won't be a disaster. Also, if you're delayed slightly and you only just make the connection, it's possible that your baggage won't. Again, the airline is obliged to bring it to you in Bali and will do so as soon as they can. But I'd recommend having a change of clothes, toiletries etc. in your carry-on so that you'll be more comfortable if your checked luggage is delayed.